# How to keep an activity loading while an overlaying transparent activity is loaded on front?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

From the `MainActivity` I switched to the `Settings` activity of Android.

I added a transparent activity on the front of the `Settings` activity.

problem is, only once `finish()` of the transparent activity is invoked, the `Settings` activity loads.

How do I get the `Settings` activity loads while the transparent activity is on the front?

**The way I'm doing it currently:**

```
void startSettingsActivity(Context context) {
   Intent settingsIntent = new Intent (context, 
   Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
   context.startActivity(settingsIntent );

   Intent transparentIntent = new Intent(context, MyTransparentActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(transparentIntent);
}
```

I think the problem is that I am using the same context for both activities.
However, I'm not able to find another way to handle this.

**What is the best way to keep the `Settings` activity loading while the transparent one is already on the front?**

Comment: why do you want to start 2 `Activities` at same time? There are `AsyncTasks`, `Background services` that could make job from `Activity`. `Activity` is representation of some values. The long work should never maked on it.

Comment: @anatoli i want the settings activity to be loaded already when the transparent activity is up, since it contains info regarding what the user ought to do in the settings activity

Comment: @ThunderWriting, after i have some read in web: your `Settings` is **not** `Activity`. It is `ContentProvider`. Try `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS)` or read [here](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter/issues/96) first answer links

Answer (score 0):

If this were in code you control, you could launch the first activity, which would then launch the transparent activity on top of itself.

However, since the settings activity is not under your control, try [`startActivities(Intent[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[])). It behaves *as if* you called `startActivity(intent[0])`, which then called `startActivity(intent[1])`, and so on.

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(context, Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
Intent transparentIntent = new Intent(context, MyTransparentActivity.class);
context.startActivities(new Intent[] {settingsIntent, transparentIntent});
```

Comment: does using `Activity` is the right way to implement this?

Answer (score -1):

use thread, specifically use **AsyncTask**, will help get this done

Comment: AsyncTask is for performing tasks not in the UI thread, like connecting to a server/http/...etc.
However, in my case, i want to "build" UI, so i need the UI thread. I might be missing something in your answer, could you please elaborate?